# Error converting data type varchar to numeric

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I am getting an error in the following query:

```sql
insert into ProductStone ( Pieces, Weight, CutChg, LotID, 
                           CatID, OrnID, StoneID, ShadeID, CutID, ChgType, SetID) 
 values (  '10',  '0.3',  'null',  '601',  'H',  '101',  
           'S',  '0',  '13',  'null',  '4' ).
```

Problem is that I am creating my query at runtime . Please tell how I can check whether the value is null or not at run time.

Part of my code which I use to build dynamic query at runtime is as follows. I changed my previous code but in some cases it is working and some cases not working with null values.

```java
  if ((updatedData.elementAt(r).get(c).get(1)==null) ||
      (updatedData.elementAt(r).get(c).get(1).equals("")))
  {
      updatedData.elementAt(r).get(c).set(1,"0");
  }
  else if (!(updatedData.elementAt(r).get(c).get(1).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("null") )) 
  {
      updatedData.elementAt(r).get(c).set(1,"0");   
  }
```

Comment: Are you really storing the string "null" or the value `null`?

Comment: please check i updated my question but in some cases it is working and other cases null is not not filtered by these checks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is being solved by putting two validations

```
//First
if ((updatedData.elementAt(r).get(c).get(1).toString().equals("null"))) 
{
updatedData.elementAt(r).get(c).set(1,"0");   
}
//Second
if (!(updatedData.elementAt(r).get(c).get(1).toString().equals("null"))) 
{
updateQuery +=updatedData.elementAt(r).get(c).get(0)+"='"+updatedData.elementAt(r).get(c).get(1)+"', " ;
insertColValsStr += " '"+updatedData.elementAt(r).get(c).get(1)+"') ";        
}
else
{
updateQuery += updatedData.elementAt(r).get(c).get(0)+"=null " ;
insertColValsStr += " null ) " ;       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if((updatedData.elementAt(r).get(c).get(1)==null) || (updatedData.elementAt(r).get(c).get(1).equals("")))
           {
             updatedData.elementAt(r).get(c).set(1,null);
           }
```

Change that piece of code and check...

One more point

```
insert into ProductStone ( Pieces, Weight, CutChg, LotID, 
CatID, OrnID, StoneID, ShadeID, CutID, ChgType, SetID) 
 values (  '10',  '0.3',  'null',  '601',  'H',  '101',  
'S',  '0',  '13',  'null',  '4' ).
```

When ever you inser the null dont put that in the quotes, convert that to the following statement and check

```
insert into ProductStone ( Pieces, Weight, CutChg, LotID, 
CatID, OrnID, StoneID, ShadeID, CutID, ChgType, SetID) 
 values (  '10',  '0.3',  null,  '601',  'H',  '101',  
'S',  '0',  '13',  null,  '4' ).
```

Comment: I updated the code and now it works fine form the code is below

Comment: please check i updated my question but in some cases it is working and other cases null is not not filtered by these checks